# Typescript declaration file not getting compiled properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this **lib.d.ts** file

```js
import { Users } from '@prisma/client';

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface User extends Users {}
    }
}
```

and I have this **passport.ts** in the same folder, where **user** is of type **Express.User**

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

the IDE doesnt complain about it, but when I run the app I get this error :

`error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'.`

This is my tsconfig.json :

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                
    "lib": ["es6"],                                    
    "module": "commonjs",                              
    "rootDir": "src",                                  
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                         
    "allowJs": true,                                   
    "outDir": "build",                                 
    "esModuleInterop": true,                       
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,          
    "strict": true,                                    
    "noImplicitAny": true,                             
    "skipLibCheck": true,                         
  }
}
```

and this is the path from tsconfig json to the file :

- src/config/passport/passport.ts
- src/config/passport/lib.d.ts

Why does that happen, ive been trying to fix this error for 2 days now.

**EDIT : I fixed the error. It had to do with how I started my app.**

**Previously I started it with this script :**

`ts-node ./src/index.ts`

**adding the --files flag fixed it for me**

`ts-node --files ./src/index.ts`

Here is an explanation : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#missing-types

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be because you are trying to import at the top of the lib.d.ts file. I had a similar problem and starting the declaration on the first line of the file fixed my problem. Try this.

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        user: import("@prisma/client").Users
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's not that in my case, because If I do this : 

```
declare global {

 namespace Express {

  interface User {

   id?: string;

  }

 }

}


export {};
```

it still doesnt work. The IDE recognizes it, but when compiling it throws an error